# Finding and replacing a value in HashMap?

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

I wrote a HashMap with the key as a String and the value as a LinkedList of Strings.

I want to write a method that consumes the key which is a string and value. Then I want find the key in the HashMap that match the given key then add the given String to the List of the Strings.

**thank guys but there is another error. 
in this line "Likes.put(s,Likes.get(s).add(fav)); ." it says :

```
Error: no suitable method found for put(java.lang.String,boolean)
    method java.util.HashMap.put(java.lang.String,java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (actual argument boolean cannot be converted to java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.String> by method invocation conversion)
    method java.util.AbstractMap.put(java.lang.String,java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (actual argument boolean cannot be converted to java.util.LinkedList<java.lang.String> by method invocation conversion)
```

I can't tell why it says "the actual argument is Boolean"! I want to insert a LinkedList no a boolean

```
class  Recomnder {

  Recomnder(){
  Likes.put("tom",new LinkedList() ); 
  Recomnder.addLikes("tom","movie tovi"); 
  }

  HashMap<String,LinkedList<String>> Likes = new HashMap<String,LinkedList<String>>(); 


 void addLikes (String name, String fav){
     for (String s : Likes.keySet()) {
         if (s.equals(name))
         Likes.put(s,Likes.get(s).add(fav));
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: The compiler message is pretty clear, you should be able to debug it by yourself.

Comment: You should use static void ... for the method addLikes() ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from changing your method to static. Change the following statement.

Before
Likes.put(s,Likes.get(s).add(fav));

After
Likes.get(s).add(fav);

In the above code, Likes.get(s).add(fav) return boolean and this return value is being added to the Map. Hence the compiler giving the error.

Just adding the String to the Likes.get(s) will do the trick as java works on references. This will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this statement:

```
Recomnder.addLikes("tom","movie tovi");
```

That way you are telling the compiler that you want to access addLikes as a static method. However it is not defined as a static method. You can only call addLikes on an instance of Recomnder. So if you change it to:

```
addLikes("tom","movie tovi");
```

it should work.
btw. try adhering to Java naming conventions. Get used to always start instance variable names with a small case letter (e.g. likes instead of Likes). That way you spot such a mistake much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Instance methods need to be called from an instance. Your addLikes method is an instance method (it doesn't have the modifier static). You need to create an instance of the class before you can call the method on it.